# Which Layout for onboarding screen

Tags: android, android-layout

For my application I created a mock up of an onboarding screen which looks like this:

[image]

Now I'm not entirely shur how to design this in an Android layout. The text below should not be so hard. The greatest problem is the top part with the gray areas. All gray parts should be `ImageView`s with an `1:1` ratio so that I can animate them separately.

What do you think which Layout (`RelativeLayout`, `ConstraintLayout`, etc.) should I use for this? I think it should be better to avoid hardcoded dp values so that it looks the same independent from the screen size and resolution. So percentage values are better here right?

**EDIT**: Here is my current layout but I can't get the 4 circles around the image in the middle...

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:padding="16dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/empty"
        android:cropToPadding="true"
        android:padding="48dp"
        android:tint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="w,1:1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.3"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ringer" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/location"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@string/empty"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="w,1:1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/timerange"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/icon"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/location" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/timerange"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@string/empty"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="w,1:1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/wifi"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/location"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/icon"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/sound_alarm" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/wifi"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@string/empty"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="w,1:1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/bluetooth"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/timerange"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/icon"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/wifi" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/bluetooth"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@string/empty"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="w,1:1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/wifi"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/icon"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/bluetooth" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="24dp"
        android:text="@string/onboardTitle1"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/timerange" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:text="@string/onboardDescrption1"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/title" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Don't know how to answer, but looks pretty

Comment: `What do you think which Layout should I use for this?` Answer - [`ConstraintLayout`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout.html).

Comment: Can you please have a look at my current layout?

Comment: is this vote answer or what? me vote for Relative Layout mix with Linear and weight ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like below;

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/infoBlue"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="16dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="bottom">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icon"
            android:layout_width="130dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:background="@color/gray"
            android:contentDescription="@string/empty"
            android:cropToPadding="true"
            android:padding="48dp"
            android:tint="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/location"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/icon"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/icon"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/icon"
            android:background="@color/gray"
            android:contentDescription="@string/empty" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/timerange"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/icon"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/icon"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/icon"
            android:background="@color/gray"
            android:contentDescription="@string/empty" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/wifi"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/icon"
            android:layout_marginEnd="40dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/icon"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/icon"
            android:background="@color/gray"
            android:contentDescription="@string/empty" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/bluetooth"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/icon"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/icon"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/icon"
            android:background="@color/gray"
            android:contentDescription="@string/empty" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

It looked like below in my case;

[image]

Comment: Refer https://www.loopwiki.com/ui-ux-design/android-onboarding-screen-example-using-viewpager/

Answer (score 0):

I would start with a `RelativeLayout` but then nest a `LinearLayout` with a fixed height inside that.

My reasoning is as follows:

- your four smaller circles are all in separate columns (do not overlap) which allows the linear layout to easily space them.
- the parent relative layout will allow you to move the linear layout up the page (so its invisible part overlaps the bigger image)
- the fixed height of the LinearLayout allows you to simply use gravity to put the circles at the top and bottom bounds to create the layout you've shown

  ```
  <RelativeLayout>
      <ImageView android:id="@+id/square" />
      <LinearLayout android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="-24dp">
           <ImageView android:foregroundGravity="top" />
           <ImageView android:foregroundGravity="bottom" />
           <ImageView android:foregroundGravity="bottom" />
           <ImageView android:foregroundGravity="top" />
      </LinearLayout>
  </RelativeLayout>
  ```

Depending on your matrix, using foreground gravity might not suit you. If that is the case, forget the fixed height for the LinearLayout and then add a top margin to the 'bottom' aligned images